# How can I evaluate the forward difference of a constant like 2?

Tags: calculus

When we apply the forward difference operator to a constant, why does it become zero? Since the forward difference of a variable $x$ is $f(x+h) - f(x)$, then why don't we write forward the difference of a constant $2$ as $2+h-2 = h$?

Comment: Constants don't change, so $2$ never equals $2+h$ (with $h\ne 0$) no matter what $x$ you consider.

Comment: Abusively denoting $2(x)$ the function that maps $x$ to $2$, $2(x)=2(x+h)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 2$ for all $x$.  Then also $f(x+h) = 2$, and so $$f(x+h) - f(x) = 2 - 2 = 0.$$